# How can I use ILogger abstractions in a .NET Library with a singleton pattern?

Tags: c#, ilogger

I have a class library that currently uses NLog for its logging purposes.  I would like to update this library to use an `ILogger<T>` abstraction from **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions** so that consumers of this library can choose their own logging frameworks.

The library uses a singleton pattern with a private constructor and *Instance* property:

```
public static MyLibrary Instance { get; } = new MyLibrary();

private MyLibrary()
{
...
}
```

What are suggestions to keep this library a singleton, yet allow consumers to provide an `ILogger` implementation at startup/object creation? Is there a way I can have this library accept a logging implementation from other applications without changing the singleton pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a global property for the logger, presumably something like

```
public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory {get;set;} = NullLoggerFactory.Instance;
```

All potential problems with global state applies, even if most logging frameworks would probably be threadsafe.

A obvious downside is that no logging will occur unless the consumer actually sets the loggerFactory. You would also need to take initialization order into account. The most obvious solution to that would be to stop using a singleton, and instead use a factory method that takes the loggerFactory. I.e.

```
public static MyLibrary CreateMyLibrary(ILoggerFactory factory)
```

If the consumer wants to put created library in a global field he is free to do so.